# Binary Search Tree Algorithm Sequence

Tags: search, binary-search-tree, binary-search

[image]

I know this has to do with the searching algorithm but looking at the sequence of numbers I still can't figure anything out.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Suppose that students actually started to do their own homework instead of getting the internet to do it for them. Your test scores are supposed to reflect _your_ abilities, not our abilities.

Comment: This should be for the Programmers site.

Comment: I am following the textbook and it is one of the textbook problems but I don't have the manual for this textbook since I bought a used copy from someone..

Comment: Look at my answer, it gives you the approach to use to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is that the numbers both lower and higher than the number you are searching for should be getting closer to the number being searched for (from each respective side). What this means is that you should not be trying a number that is more distant than a number already tried (on a respective side).

For example, if you are searching for 500, and you've tried 250, then 750, you cannot try for example 230 or 780, because they are more distant from 500 on their respective sides than the numbers you've already tried (i.e., 250 and 750).

So, without giving away the answer, since this is clearly a homework question, you now have enough information to answer your own question.

Comment: I got it! I know C is strange by that way of thinking and D.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this article: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

I think what you may have to do is map the numbers out programmatically. Let me know if this helps..